# C#: test runner skips a test for no clear reason

Tags: c#, .net

I'm a C# newbie and I wrote a brand new unit test:

```
namespace ServerUnitTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class ServerCommonConfigTest
    {
        public const string type = TestType.SimpleUnitTests;

        [TestCategory(type), TestMethod]
        public void my_test()
        {
            var serverCommonConfig = new ServerCommonConfig();
            serverCommonConfig.Init();
            Assert.IsTrue(true);
        }
    }
}
```

After compiling the test projects and running the command:

```
 dotnet vstest ServerUnitTests.dll /TestCaseFilter:TestCategory=SimpleUnitTests /logger:trx /Platform:x64 /Blame /logger:console;
```

I got the output:

> Results File:
> C:\South\bin\x64_Debug\Server\net6.0\TestResults\matan.bar-lev_xmcybe_XM-MATANBL_2023-05-18_11_49_42.trx
>
> Passed!  - Failed:     0, Passed:     1, Skipped:     0, Total:     1,
> Duration: 106 ms - ServerUnitTests.dll (net6.0)

It means that the test is discovered, but skipped.
Do you understand why it was skipped? I want this test to run. How to do it?

Comment: From the output it doesn't say it was skipped, it says it passed. "Passed: 1" and "Skipped: 0".